# Доказательство Zig-Zig шага

Tags: алгоритм, дерево

Возник вопрос связанный с одним из уроков видеолекции которую я сейчас смотрю.

Пусть даны два дерева - изначальное и дерево после zig-zig шага :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посчитаем учетную стоимость  данной операции.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где она является: сумма рангов нового дерева(После zig-zig шага) минус сумма рангов исходного дерева.
Теперь обратим внимание на корневые вершины деревьев.
 - т.к их ранг равен, то мы можем вычеркнуть их из уравнения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, проведем оценку сверху. r'(u) и r'(w) - их при оценке сверху можно оценить как r'(v)
 в изначальном дереве (до zig-zig шага)  - вершины u и w стоят выше вершины v - поэтому при оценке сверху относительно вершины v в исходном
 дереве - следует просто считать потенциал вершин r(u) и r(w) за r(v) с противоположным знаком.
В итоге получаем выражение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Теперь вопрос:** *почему индекс 2 меняется на 3* ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала я подумал что это +1 как учетная стоимость за фактическое действие, но оказалось, что вот это +1 нужно выполнять для каждой вершины - что ломает все доказательство - там далее в лекции это объясняется и также как этого избежать, Но сейчас не об этом, а о том, почему если это не +1 за фактическое действие, то откуда взялся индекс 3 ?

Comment: в том то и дело, что на этом внимание не акцентируется

Comment: просто идет следующий материал